# wxPython: using TextCtrl to wrap text leads to unwanted extra space below the wrapped text

Tags: python, resize, wxpython

I've been trying to use `TextCtrl` to wrap a long string of text in an app. Beneath the `TextCtrl` object is a `ListBox` object. There is no border/padding between the two (i.e., `border` is not set). However, whenever I open the app, there is always some extra white space between the `TextCtrl` object and the `ListBox` object. The space disappears only if I try to resize the window (however slightly). The code below demonstrates the issue. Two screenshots below the code show exactly what I mean.

```
class MyApp(wx.Frame):
def __init__(self, parent, title):
    super(MyApp, self).__init__(parent, style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE,
                                   title=title, size=(500, 515))
    self.SetBackgroundColour('white')
    self.myGridSizer = wx.GridBagSizer(4,3)

    #App title
    Title = wx.StaticText(self, label = "My Application")
    Title.SetFont(wx.Font(16, family = wx.DEFAULT, style = wx.NORMAL, 
                          weight = wx.BOLD, faceName = 'Consolas'))
    self.myGridSizer.Add(Title, pos = (0, 0), span = (1, 3), flag = wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, border=10)


    #Input textctrl label
    input_label = wx.StaticText(self, label="Input File: ")
    input_label.SetFont(wx.Font(9, family = wx.DEFAULT, style = wx.NORMAL, 
                          weight = wx.NORMAL, faceName = 'Consolas'))
    self.myGridSizer.Add(input_label, pos = (1, 0), span = (1,1), flag = wx.EXPAND|wx.TOP|wx.RIGHT|wx.LEFT, border = 10)

    #Input textctrl
    input = wx.TextCtrl(self, size=(-1,-1), style = wx.BORDER_SIMPLE)
    self.myGridSizer.Add(input, pos = (1, 1), span = (1,1), flag = wx.EXPAND|wx.TOP|wx.RIGHT, border = 10)

    #Input button
    button = wx.lib.buttons.GenButton(self, id = 1,  
                                      size = (-1, -1), 
                                      label = "OPEN",
                                      style = wx.BORDER_SIMPLE)
    self.myGridSizer.Add(button, pos = (1, 2), span = (1,1), flag = wx.TOP|wx.RIGHT, border = 10)

    #Long text to be wrapped
    note = "This is a fairly long text string that I would like to wrap. This is a fairly long text string that I would like to wrap. This is a fairly long text string that I would like to wrap. This is a fairly long text string that I would like to wrap. This is a fairly long text string that I would like to wrap. This is a fairly long text string that I would like to wrap. This is a fairly long text string that I would like to wrap. This is a fairly long text string that I would like to wrap. This is a fairly long text string that I would like to wrap."
    noteCtrl = wx.TextCtrl(self, value = note, 
                     style = wx.TE_READONLY|wx.TE_MULTILINE|wx.TE_NO_VSCROLL|wx.BORDER_NONE, size=(-1, -1))
    self.myGridSizer.Add(noteCtrl, pos = (2, 1), span = (1,1), flag = wx.EXPAND|wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT, border = 10)



    #LISTBOX
    listBoxFields = wx.ListBox(self, choices=[], name='listBox1', style=wx.LB_EXTENDED|wx.BORDER_SIMPLE, size=(-1, -1))
    self.myGridSizer.Add(listBoxFields, pos = (3, 1), span=(1,1), flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT|wx.BOTTOM, border = 10)

    self.myGridSizer.AddGrowableCol(1)
    self.myGridSizer.AddGrowableRow(3)
    self.SetSizer(self.myGridSizer)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    MainFrame = MyApp(None, title = "My Application")
    MainFrame.Show()
    MainFrame.Centre()
    app.MainLoop()
```

This is what the app looks like. Note the space indicated by the green arrow
[image]

This is what the app looks like after I increased the width of the window very very slightly. Note the narrower space indicated by the red arrow. 
[image]

In this case, the difference is not so dramatic. But in some other cases I've seen, the extra space can take up to 1/3-1/2 of the window estate. **I wonder how I can remove this extra space without having to resize the window**

Answer (score 0):

This works fine under Linux.
I suggest that you lose `|wx.BORDER_NONE` from the line:

```
noteCtrl = wx.TextCtrl(self, value = note, 
                 style = wx.TE_READONLY|wx.TE_MULTILINE|wx.TE_NO_VSCROLL|wx.BORDER_NONE, size=(-1, -1))
```

as I don't think that it is valid syntax.
If that doesn't fix it, try losing the `|wx.TE_NO_VSCROLL` from `noteCtrl` as well.